# How to append a string into an array using a variable? Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I recently started learning to code and I am encountering an issue with appending a string that has been turned into a variable into an array. 
Here is what the console said:

cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'

Here is my code:

```
var randomList = [String]()

func getList(inputList:Array<String>) -> Array<String>{

    randomList = inputList

    return randomList
}

func addItem(item: String...) -> String{

    randomList.append(item)

    return "\(item) was added"
}

func getItem(x: Int) -> String{
    return randomList[x]
}
```

Comment: That's because you are trying to append array of item to randomList. The type of *item* is array not String. So to put, loop through *item* and then append the looped value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your code to:

```
func addItem(item: String...) -> String{

    randomList.append(contentsOf: item)

    return "\(item) was added"
}
```

Then you will be able to add 1 or more strings like this:

```
addItem(item: "Hello", "you", "there")
```

The resulting array will look like this:

```
print(randomList)
```

["Hello", "you", "there"]

---

To append a single string:

```
let singleString = "hi"

addItem(item: singleString)
```

To append a multiple strings:

```
let stringOne = "one"
let stringTwo = "two"
let stringThree = "three"

addItem(item: stringOne, stringTwo, stringThree)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are appending an array of strings not a single string. `item` is an array of strings.

You can remove the `...` to append a single item.

```
func addItem(item: String) -> String{

    randomList.append(item)

    return "\(item) was added"
}
```

or if you want to append array of string use `randomList.append(contentsOf: item)`

```
func addItem(item: String...) -> String{

    randomList.append(contentsOf: item)   

    return "\(item) was added"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Variadic Parameter (...) which is treated as an array.

That's what the error message says. You are passing an array of strings where a single string is expected.

There are two solutions:

1. Change the `item` argument to `String`:

   ```
   func addItem(item: String) -> String{
   ```
2. Use the API to append the contents of an array:

   ```
   randomList.append(contentsOf: item)
   ```